# Remove a permission from a user in Sentry

Tags: php, cartalyst-sentry

I'm using Sentry 2 to build a basic RBAC system, I want to ignore Groups completely if I can, assigning permissions/roles directly to a user.

As a superuser, I can currently assign permissions to any other user in the database and this works perfectly. What I'd like to be able to do is explicitly remove that permission from the array of permissions rather than assigning it a `0` or `-1` value to keep that column clean when permissions are changing regularly.

I am aware that the `hasPermission` method will still work correctly in this way, however, my OCD wants to remove it from the database.

Is there a way for me to do this?

Comment: `however my OCD wants to remove it from database` I can relate to this 100%